# Nodemon not restarting when html file is modified

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I'm learning Node.js, my demo has two files:

- `/server.js`
- `/public/index.html`

`/server.js` will get `/public/index.html` and then return to the client.

I'd like to use `nodemon` to auto reload when `/public/index.html` is modified. However, it seems like `nodemon` only works when I modify `/server.js` and not when `/public/index.html` is modified.

I'm using `nodemon server.js` to starting the server.

Answer (score 42):

Just specify watching `html` on the `nodemon` command line (or better yet, add a config file).

From the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list):

> By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .coffee, .litcoffee,
>   and .json extensions. If you use the `--exec` option and monitor app.py
>   nodemon will monitor files with the extension of .py. However, you can
>   specify your own list with the -e (or --ext) switch like so:
>
> `nodemon -e js,jade` Now nodemon will restart on any changes to files in
>   the directory (or subdirectories) with the extensions .js, .jade.

Comment: Just to add to this, since you've made mention of using a `nodemon.json` file, [here's the sample](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md) config from the docs. You can use the `ext` property to specify which file extensions to watch.

Comment: `nodemon -e *` will force it to watch for ALL file changes in the folder.

Comment: it rebuilds, but doesnt refresh the browser page

Comment: `nodemon -e '*'` for me. Without quotes, bash provides file from my current directory

Answer (score 17):

Add `nodemon.json` configuration file worked for me.

```
{
  "ext": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use a comma separated string to add multiple extensions in `nodemon.json`

```
{
    "ext": "js,html"
}
```

Comment: Or if running from command line, `nodemon -e js,html app.js`

Answer (score 10):

Here's another possibility: using your existing [`package.json`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#packagejson) file:

```json
"name": "app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"nodemonConfig": {
  "ext": "js,html"
}
```

Just keep in mind nodemon will only be checking for `.js` and `.html` files from now on. You'll have to add your own files if you have more.

Answer (score 2):

Add watching extension for all in package.json file do something like with your scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -e * app.js"
  }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add a nodemon.json file, inside the file do something like:

```
{
   “watch”  : [ “filename.html”]
}
```

Restart nodemon, that works with me.